# Chrome identifying field as "address" for autofill incorrectly

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

I have a webform with multiple text inputs, quite recently one specifically started having it's autofill linked to "City" somehow and Chrome is only giving options from the stored addresses in the browser.

The name and type aren't even close to what should match in the specs for the browsers regex I've seen online, and even playing with the "x-autocompletetype" I found on other forums seems to have no impact.

```html
<label for="spec-Storage Capacity"> 6. Storage Capacity </label>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="spec-Storage Capacity" name="spec-Storage Capacity" x-autocompletetype="Storage Capacity">
```

Up until recently, it was storing what we had been filling in here (e.g. "16 GB") but now we just get the city list from the browser.

Also note: I know it's not that the name has spaces because other form elements look just like this and work correctly.

Comment: 'Capacity' ends in 'city' so it may be a really lazy regex.

Comment: Facepalm.  I knew it would be something brutally obvious haha.  Thank you!

Comment: @AdeolaBannis - say that as an answer instead of comment so I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "city" at the end of "Capacity" seems to be triggering the autofill. I guess the regex is aggressive so it can match cases like [shipping-city](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a generic answer for when fields are not autofilling correctly, use the autofill attribute to specify the correct value to autofill. Acceptable value seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

example:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" autocomplete="given-name"/>
<input type="text" name="lastName" autocomplete="family-name"/>
```

In this particular case, there may not be a definitive solution, as the name "Capacity" may be confusing the field with a city field (since 'city' is a substring of 'capacity'). If your form has a city field, make sure you add `autocomplete="address-level2"` to your city's input tag, although this may have unintended consequences if your users live in a place with many administrative levels.

If you do not have a city field, try making a hidden field like so:

`<input type="hidden" autocomplete="address-level2"/>`

Not sure if that would work. another alternative would be to do:

`<input type="text" autocomplete="address-level2" style="height: 0; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;"/>`